# Use checkbox for list-style-type in unordered list in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a bulleted list on a webpage and I need my bullets to function like checkboxes which the user can select. I want to, then, use them to execute some function based on the list elements that the user has selected. Also, each of those `<li>` further contains a `description list`.

`list-style-type` does not have such an option. I tried to append an input tag to the `<li>` such:

`<input type= "checkbox">`

But this [looks too ugly](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bKVBmB) as the checkbox is not present on a different line that the rest of the html inside `<li>`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your question is not very clear.

`list-style-type` is used to change the aesthetics of the bullets, but they can't have a specific function. In the example below, I used this property to remove the bullets.

```css
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox"> whatever</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"> whatever</li>
 <ul>
```

**EDIT**

Based on your fiddle, you could try this so the checkbox will be aligned with the word.

```
<ul>
    <li>

        <dl>
          <dt> <input type="checkbox"> Coffee </dt>
          <dd> Black, Strong <dd>
      </dl>
    </li>
    <li>

        <dl>
          <dt> <input type="checkbox"> Tea </dt>
          <dd> Exotic </dd>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry I did not explain it clearly - each `<li>` element further contains a description list. So, this is how it looks - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bKVBmB

Comment: So you want the checkbox aligned with "Cofee" for example ?

Comment: Yeah this is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Is it something like this that you're looking for.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <dl>
      <dt> <label><input type="checkbox">Coffee</label> </dt>
      <dd> Black, Strong<dd>
    </dl>
  </li>
  <li>
    <dl>
      <dt> <label><input type="checkbox">Tea</label> </dt>
      <dd> Exotic<dd>
    </dl>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a list with the `list-style-type` set to `none`

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox"> check 1
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox"> check 2
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox"> check 3
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox"> check 4
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox"> check 5
    </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox"> check 6
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Codepen example: https://codepen.io/Washable/pen/MXabVO

Comment: Sorry I did not explain it clearly - each `<li>` element further contains a description list. So, this is how it looks - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bKVBmB

So, as you may notice the checkbox and the contents are present on different lines. That is undesirable. It would be really awesome if you could suggest solution for this.